# Omitting Domain Registrant/Admin Name

Tags: domains, facebook, whois

I've noticed, with a quick domain lookup, that Facebook omits some informations in the Whois Records. Instead of writing a real name, the Registrant/Amin/Tech Name is "Domain Administrator". How is it possible? Is it OK to write a fake/placeholder name in the records?

---

[image: Whois Records]

So, if I register a domain that doesn't support the Whois Privacy service, can I put a placeholder name such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Most domain registrars allow you to register privately. So there is a real name on record, just not publicly visible to whois queries

2) In my experience, you can use "Domain Admin" or "Domain Webmaster" or "Fake Name" when registering. So long as the payment goes through.